# Handle controlled checbox

Tags: reactjs, atlaskit

I have a form where I am rendering checkbox from map, how can I handle when someone unchecked box? Now i am using isChecked to set it.

```
import React, {ChangeEvent, Fragment, useCallback, useEffect, useState} from 'react';

import Button from '@atlaskit/button/standard-button';
import {Checkbox} from '@atlaskit/checkbox';
import {Grid, GridColumn} from '@atlaskit/page';

import Form, {CheckboxField, Field, FormFooter} from '@atlaskit/form';
import {ValueType as Value} from "@atlaskit/select/types";
import Select from "@atlaskit/select";
import {sentinelVulnerabilities} from "../constants";
import {invoke} from "@forge/bridge";

interface Option {
    label: string;
    value: string;
}

BasicConfiguration.defaultProps = {
    jiraIssuePriorities: [],
}

const columns = 12;
export default function BasicConfiguration({jiraIssuePriorities, initPriorites, allowedVulnerabilities}: any) {


    const [allowedVul, setAllowedVul] = useState<any | null>(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            await invoke("getStorage", {name: 'vulnerabilities_allowed'}).then(setAllowedVul);
        })();
    }, [])

    const jiraIssuePrioritiesOptions = jiraIssuePriorities.map(({name, id}: any) => ({
        label: name,
        value: id,
    }));

    const shouldBySelected = (prioritySentinel: string) => {
        if (initPriorites === undefined || Object.keys(prioritySentinel).length === 0.)
            return '';

        return initPriorites[prioritySentinel];
    }

    const shouldBeChecked = (vulnName: string): boolean => {

        if (allowedVul === undefined || Object.keys(allowedVul).length === 0.) {
            return false;
        }
        return allowedVul.includes(vulnName);
    }

    const onSubmit = async (data: any) => {
        //Store mapping
        await invoke("setStorage", {name: "vulnerabilities_allowed", data: data.vulnerabilities});

        let priorities = {
            note: undefined,
            critical: undefined,
            high: undefined,
            medium: undefined,
            low: undefined
        };
        if (data.hasOwnProperty('critical')) {
            priorities.critical = data.critical.label;
        }

        if (data.hasOwnProperty('high')) {
            priorities.high = data.high.label;
        }

        if (data.hasOwnProperty('medium')) {
            priorities.medium = data.medium.label;
        }

        if (data.hasOwnProperty('low')) {
            priorities.low = data.low.label;
        }

        if (data.hasOwnProperty('note')) {
            priorities.note = data.note.label;
        }

        await invoke("setStorage", {name: 'vuln_priorities', data: priorities});
    }


    return (
        <div style={{
            display: 'flex',
            width: '600px',
            margin: '0 auto',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            paddingTop: 50,
        }}>

            <h3>Map Sentinel Vulnerabilities and Jira Issues</h3>
            <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                {({formProps}) => (
                    <form {...formProps}>

                        {
                            sentinelVulnerabilities.map((element) => {
                                const isChecked = shouldBeChecked(element.value);
                                return <div>

                                    <Grid spacing="compact" columns={columns}>

                                        <GridColumn medium={4} css={{paddingTop: '5px'}}>
                                            <CheckboxField name="vulnerabilities" value={element.value}>
                                                {({fieldProps}) => <Checkbox {...fieldProps} label={element.label} isChecked={isChecked}
                                                />}
                                            </CheckboxField>


                                        </GridColumn>
                                        <GridColumn medium={8}>
                                            <Field<Value<Option>>
                                                name={element.value}
                                                isRequired={true}
                                                defaultValue={{
                                                    value: shouldBySelected(element.value).toLowerCase(),
                                                    label: shouldBySelected(element.value)
                                                }}

                                            >

                                            </Field>
                                        </GridColumn>
                                    </Grid>
                                </div>
                            })
                        }


                        
        </div>
    );
}
```

What i want to achive is when page render have checkbox checked based on function `shouldBeChecked()` but I want that user can uncheck the box and submit the form. For now user is not able to unchecked the box, checkbox is always checked.

Answer (score 0):

`isChecked` should be in a state, so it's value can be changed between different renders, otherwise it's value will always be the same returend from `const isChecked = shouldBeChecked(element.value);` on the first render within the map function.

And it's better to evaluate `isChecked` outside map function, because every time the component renders, the `shouldBeChecked` function will be running again which assins value to `isChecked`. So it'd be better to put this `const isChecked = shouldBeChecked(element.value);` in useEffect with empty dependency.